# learning jquery syntax for if and else function

Tags: jquery, syntax

I'm trying to write and an if or else function if an element is visible on the screen.  Any help would be great

```
function isVisable( element, container ){

        var elementTop = $(element).offset().top,
            elementHeight = $(element).height(),
            containerTop = $(container).offset().top,
            containerHeight = $(container).height();

        return ((((elementTop - containerTop) + elementHeight) > 0) && ((elementTop - containerTop) < containerHeight));
    }





    if (isVisable(".section section_2", ".project_images")); {
        $('.top').hide();
    }

    else {
        $('.top').show();
    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are trying to solve?

Comment: Is the syntax correct in the if and else statement?

Comment: no...! you have extra semicolon on if statement

Comment: semicolon in the IF not required

Comment: are you trying to check if the element is visible (i.e opacity, display etc) or whether it is in the boundaries of the scrolled area?

Comment: @Makrand it is actually syntax error in this case since there are 2 statements between `if` and `else` (should be visible in browser's console/dev tools)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If eventually all you are doing is choosing whether to do `hide()` or `show()` you can use `fadeToggle();`

```
$('.top').fadeToggle();
```

If it is contingent on ANOTHER element's visibility you can use:

```
$('#another_element').is(':visible') ? $('.top').hide() : $('.top').show();
```

And lastly, if you must use your custom function to determine the elements visibility PLUS position, you can use:

```
isVisable(".section section_2", ".project_images") ? $('.top').hide() : $('.top').show();
```

More efficient + looks cleaner + not reinventing the wheel, although we all like to :)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks yani this helped me the most. But joadha corrected my syntax. The position plus visibility was crucial.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error right here:

```
if (isVisable(".section section_2", ".project_images")); {
    $('.top').hide();
}
else {
    $('.top').show();
}
```

Drop the semicolon here `".project_images")); {`

Answer (score 0):

.length can be used to chck whether element is visible or not.

it can be very simply used such as :

> `$("element-to-be-checked").length`